# Trying to store hashed username in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, hash, md5

I am trying to hash the username using the JavaScript-MD5 plugin, and then store it to the database to use with Jdenticon.  I am able to hash the password and log it to the console using `var hash = md5($scope.username);` but am unable to pass it to my newUser variable.

1. Registration Controller

   ```
   $scope.register = function(){
   var hash = md5($scope.username);
   console.log(hash);
   var newUser = {
     email: $scope.email,
     password: $scope.password,
     username: $scope.username,
     userHash: hash
   };

   $http.post('/users/register', newUser).then(function(){
     $scope.email = '';
     $scope.password = '';
     $scope.username = '';
     userHash = '';
   };
   ```
2. Registration Route:

   ```
   app.post('/users/register', function(req, res) {

     bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
       bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
         var user = new User({
           email: req.body.email,
           password: hash,
           username: req.body.username,
           userHash: req.body.userHash
         });
         console.log(user);

         user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) return res.send(err);

            return res.send();
         });
       });
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: any errors in your client side console? What does your node console log?

Comment: what value shown in server side for `req.body.userHash`?

Comment: There is no value shown for the userHash.  Logged test user: `{ created: Tue Apr 19 2016 15:37:25 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
  _id: 57168933dbe10f0c2860c180,
  username: 'green',
  password: '$2a$10$U4pqSpgjM74pqSpgjM7NwEj8BnR4I.uWlODNXyld2NHmj0iGBgcETawCCZkk0G',
  email: 'green@blue.com' }`

Comment: `userHash ` exist in your `User` model?

Comment: It was not, thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you may missed `userHash` property in your `User` model that's why you can't store `userHash` in your database.

So you should include first `userHash` in your `User` model then should be working fine.

like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema= new Schema({
    username : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    },
    userHash:{
        type: String
    }
});
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```